# error while update method on boolean

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to update method in Laravel but error is:

> "Call to a member function tradereason() on boolean"

I also check same question of other people asked but **there're a lot of different in my process**. I have lot tables.

let me show you my `create` code and `update` method coding.

**Create** method code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tradeID= Auth::user()->trade()->create($input);
    $input   = $request->all();
    $reasons = $request->input('reason');

    //Loop for creating KEY as Value
    $data = [];

    foreach($reasons as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = ['reason_id' => $value];
    };

    if( $data > 0 ) {
        foreach ($data as $datum) {
            $tradeID->tradereason()->save(new TradeReason($datum));
        }
    }
}
```

this is my tring code for **update** method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
            $tradeID= Auth::user()->trade()->whereId($id)->first()->update($input);
    $input   = $request->all();
    $reasons = TradeReason::whereId($id)->first();
    $reasons->update($input);
    $reasons->tradereason()->sync($request->input('reason'));

    $data = [];

    foreach($reasons as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = ['reason_id' => $value];
    };

    if( $data > 0 ) {
        foreach ($data as $datum) {
            $tradeID->tradereason()->whereId($id)->first()->update($datum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But... where is defined $tradeID ?

Comment: in both methods `$tradeID` is not defined

Comment: I am sorry for adding `$tradeID`. I have added in question it. @Amarnasan @lagbox

Comment: Check that the `create` function is not returning a boolean...

Comment: yes `create` function is working but problem is into `update function` @Amarnasan

Comment: The error message says you are trying a tradereason function on a boolean. So $tradeID must be a boolean. So `Auth::user()->trade()->whereId($id)->first()->update($input)` is not returning a model but a boolean. Check that out.

Comment: What should I do in my code? @Amarnasan

Answer (score 0):

Calling `update` on the Builder returns an `'int'`. Calling `update` on the Model returns a `'bool'`. They don't return Model instances.

```
// bool
$tradeID= Auth::user()->trade()->whereId($id)->first()->update($input);
```

The model instance would be what is returned from the `first` call:

```
$tradeID = Auth::user()->trade()->whereId($id)->first(); // assuming it finds a record
```

You can update that, you can use it in the foreach loop.

Comment: In this case, What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`update` returns a boolean. So, don't overwrite `$tradeID` with the results of `update`.

```
$tradeID = Auth::user()->trade()->whereId($id)->first();
$tradeID->update($input);
```

Comment: error changed after adding above code :  `"Call to a member function update() on null"`

Comment: That's because no trade with that id was found ( and then Auth::user()->trade()->whereId($id)->first() returns null). Then you'd better add some error managing code to prevent reaching that line.

Comment: there is also trade id but, how is it null?

Comment: Don't know, sorry Kinnari, that goes beyond the original question and you must debug your application and find out why something you thought was there is actually not.